# How to call a class method that I initialized as an object?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Code where i inicialized class

```cs
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TObj).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                var sourceAttrs = prop.GetCustomAttribute<Reference>();
                if (sourceAttrs != null)
                {
                    Type entityType = sourceAttrs.ReferenceType;
                    Type openGenericType = typeof(LinkedEntityProvider<,>);
                    Type closedGenericType = openGenericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TObj), entityType);
                    object instanceLinkedEntityProvider = Activator.CreateInstance(closedGenericType, new object[] { Database, prop });

                }
            }
```

I need to call method of instanceLinkedEntityProvider. Is It even possible to do this?

Comment: Cast to Type and use GetMethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe through casting like

```cs
(LinkedEntityProvider)instanceLinkedEntityProvider.MyMethod();
```

or through the use of `dynamic` keyword

```cs
dynamic instanceLinkedEntityProvider = Activator.CreateInstance(closedGenericType, new object[] { Database, prop });
instanceLinkedEntityProvider.MyMethod(); //throws exception if method doesn't exist at run-time
```

which bypasses compile-time checks.

Or through even more `Reflection` where you parse all methods in the object you just created, using the `GetMethod` method of the `Type` class.